# Как получить заголовок?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение и хочу при переходе на сайт какое-то, достать ссылку m3u8 из заголовка, но почему-то мне в консоль ничего не выводит. Помогите пожалуйста, что тут не так? Поправьте пожалуйста :(

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "M3U8 Extractor",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    var extension = details.url.split('.').pop();
    if(extension == 'm3u8' ){
        console.log(details.url);
    }

}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
});
```